# Histogram equalization gives me all black image

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning

I am studying image processing and I am writing a code to do a Histogram equalization, but the output always give me an all black image.

**This is my code:**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc, math
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open('/home/thaidy/Desktop/ex.jpg').convert('L')
#converting to ndarray
img1 = np.asarray(img)

#converting to 1D
fl = img1.flatten()

#histogram and the bins are computed
hist, bins = np.histogram(img1,256,[0,255])

#cdf computed
cdf = hist.cumsum()

#places where cdf = 0 is ignored
#rest stored in cdf_m
cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf,0)

#histogram eq is performed
num_cdf_m = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min())*255
den_cdf_m =  (cdf_m.max()-cdf_m.min())*255
cdf_m = num_cdf_m/den_cdf_m

#the masked places are now 0
cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_m,0).astype('uint8')
#cdf values assigned in the flattened array
im2 = cdf[fl]
#transformin in 2D
im3 = np.reshape(im2,img1.shape)
im4 = Image.fromarray(im3)
im4.save('/home/thaidy/Desktop/output.jpg')
im4.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cdf needs to be normalized before the equalization.

One way to do that is to set the optional parameter *density* of np.histogram to `True`:

`hist, bins = np.histogram(img1,256,[0,255],density=True)`

Other way is to divide cdf after computation by total pixel count:

```
cdf = hist.cumsum()
cdf /= cdf[-1]
```

I would also change the equalization part to simply:

```
T = (255 * cdf).astype(np.uint8)
im2 = T[fl]
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) suggests to use this transformation formula instead:

```
T = (np.ceil(256 * cdf) - 1).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: `cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf,0)

#histogram eq is performed
T = (255 * cdf).astype(np.int8)
#cdf values assigned in the flattened array
im2 = T[fl]
#transformin in 2D
im3 = np.reshape(im2,img1.shape)
im4 = Image.fromarray(im3).convert('RGB')
im4.save('/home/thaidy/Desktop/output.jpg')

im4.show()`
You mean like this? I had to add convert('RGB') to the im4 conversion, otherwise was giving me an error, but I dont know how right is it.
Anyway, it seems to be everything okay now. Thank you very much.